# Как извлечь записи из базы данных Oracle в android

Tags: java, android, сервер, get, клиент

Сделал логирование, регистрацию, добавление в базу новых записей. Осталось только извлекать с сервера базы данных информацию в edittext в андроид студио, как это осуществить? Имею класс с методом GET

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public static final int POST = 0;
public static final int GET = 1;

   public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

   try {
       if (method == 0) {
           DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
           httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
           HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
           HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
           is = httpEntity.getContent();
       } else if (method == 1) {
           DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
           url += "?" + paramString;
           HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
           HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
           HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
           is = httpEntity.getContent();
       }
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   try{
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,     "utf-8"),8);
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       String line;
       while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
           builder.append(line).append("\n");
       }
       is.close();
       json = builder.toString();
   }
   catch (IOException e){
       Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error convertong result " + e.toString());
   }

   try {
   jObj = new JSONObject(json);
   }catch (JSONException e){
       Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
   }
   return jObj;
}
}
```

И имею недоработанный класс окна приложения куда должна вставляться информация из БД, помогите информацией как доделать извлечение инфы в edittext

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class StoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//
Button getData;
EditText ID_ORDER;
EditText ID_CUSTOMER;
EditText ID_PARKING;
EditText MESTO;
EditText START_T;
   EditText END_T;
    EditText PRICE;
    final static String NOT_CONNECT = "NOT_CONNECT";
    final static String SUCCESS = "SUCCESS";
    final static String FAILED = "FAILED";
//
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_story);
    getData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getData);
    ID_ORDER = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ID_ORDER);
    ID_CUSTOMER = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ID_CUSTOMER);
    ID_PARKING = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ID_PARKING);
    MESTO = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MESTO);
    START_T = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.START_T);
    END_T = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.END_T);
    PRICE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PRICE);
}

    public void setGetData_Click(View v) {


    AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
           /* JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            List<NameValuePair> storyord = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONObject json =    jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://5.19.187.230/getorders.php", JSONParser.GET, storyord);*/
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            if (result != null) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                String res = "";
                try {
                    res = result.getString("status");
                    switch (res) {
                        case NOT_CONNECT:
                            Toast toast_not_connect = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Сервер недоступен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast_not_connect.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast_not_connect.show();
                           // StoryActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                            break;

                        case SUCCESS:
                            Toast toast_success = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Данные успешно загружены!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast_success.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast_success.show();
                           // StoryActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                            break;

                        case FAILED:
                            Toast toast_failed =     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Данные не были получены!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast_failed.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast_failed.show();
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    task.execute(/**/);
}
}
```

Comment: Неужели никто не знает ответа как извлечь данные из базы в клиентское приложение?